# Swagger and WebAPI (Swashbuckle) - making the /swagger endpoint private?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I just installed Swashbuckle in my WebAPI project and so far so good, though the `/swagger` api endpoint is public.

I'd like to only allow access to my mobile app developer.  How can I hide my API behind a password or require forms auth here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this with the below:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        string username = null;
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name != null) {
            username = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToLower();
        }
        if (IsSwagger(request) && username != "Admin") {
            var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
        else {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    private bool IsSwagger(HttpRequestMessage request) {
        return request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/swagger");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project if hosted under IIS, you can use either [Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628(v=ws.10).aspx) (with proper access rights on site folder) or [basic authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(v=ws.10).aspx) on your IIS website, and disable Anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 0):

@bsoulier answer is perfectly reasonable. Another way is to use JavaScript/AJAX.

I have not tried securing the actual swagger-ui index page, since most of the time authentication on the endpoints is enough.

But any JavaScript can easily be injected into the `index` page or you can use your own custom `index` page. That means you can use any authentication that you want to. Simply create a simple HTML form and use AJAX to make a call to login the user before allowing them to see any content or before redirecting them to the real swagger-ui page.

Injecting JavaScript files into the swagger-ui page from `SwaggerConfig`:

```
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "Your.Namespace.testScript1.js");
```

Injecting custom index page into the swagger-ui page from `SwaggerConfig`:

```
c.CustomAsset("index", containingAssembly, "Your.Namespace.index.html");
```